# Wrong file content after the upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Consider this form:

```
<form class="well">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label><input id="exampleInputFile" type="file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" class="form-control-file">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"><button type="submit" onclick="submitForm();" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right">Submit</button></div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

And this javascript:

```
<script>
function submitForm() 
{
    console.log("Fetching the file...");
    var input = document.getElementById('input[type="file"]');
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', input.files[0]);
    console.log(file.size);
    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/' + #{bucket} + '/o?uploadType=media&name=sample.txt', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    }).then(function(res){ console.log(res.json()); });
}
</script>
```

It uploads a file invoking the Google Cloud Storage API: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert

However, the received file looks like that:

Content:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZBAeI3W6nEzJeW7r--
```

Type: `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryZBAeI3W6nEzJeW7r`

What am I actually doing wrong?

Also, is it possible to set up a page refresh right after the upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You uploaded the file as form data, it should just be a plain file

```
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/' + #{bucket} + '/o?uploadType=media&name=sample.txt', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: input.files[0]
}).then(function(res){ console.log(res.json()); });
```

Also you might want to prevent the form from submitting when you push the button by changing the button from a submit button to a normal button. `type="button"`

Comment: How can I obtain the file-size and mime type in this way?

Comment: size `input.files[0].size`, mime type `input.files[0].type`

Comment: Great, the upload now works very fine. Just one thing: I am not able to get the response body `console.log(res.json())` does not show content within the console.

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(res)`?

Comment: I did try: `... }).then(function(res){ console.log('test!'); });`, but nothing appears inside the console.